# How to set a default Value in case of Empty when using Optional

Tags: java

I have got an Emp Object  , if the name is empty or null , I want to have a default value

I have tried setting default value to Mark , but this is not working ,seeing blank only

This is my program

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "";

        Emp emp = new Emp();
        emp.setName(str);

        String value = Optional.ofNullable(emp).map(e -> e.getName()).orElse("Mark");

        System.out.println(value);

    }

}

class Emp {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: `""` is not null, so the default value is not used.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Optional. The Emp is non-null, neither do name. You could check for emptiness in setName() or in map to replace it with null.

Answer (score 1):

When you create you Emp, you set the name in the next row with `emp.setName(str)`.

Here you have already set the string to a blank string by using
`String str = "";`

Therefore the name of the Emp is no longer null, it is "" (a blank String).

By not setting the name it will remain null and will thereby be named "Mark" when the code is run.

Comment: ya , I am aware of it , so is it not possible with blank ??

Comment: No, because then the Optional will not be null so it will not receive it's defaultvalue

Comment: That's not entitely true, you can use the `filter` method of the optional to treat empty strings as nulls